# Query works on PhpMyadmin but not on my server

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Here are my tables:
'*modules-settings*' with columns: *module_ticker* | *name* | *module_code* |.
'*modules-users*' with columns: | *role* | *module_id* | *module_order* |.

This query #1 works:

```
SELECT `modules-settings`.module_code 
FROM `modules-settings` 
JOIN `modules-users` 
 ON `modules-users`.module_id=`modules-settings`.module_ticker WHERE role='N'
```

but not query #2:

```
SELECT `modules-settings`.module_code, `modules-users`.module_order 
FROM `modules-settings` 
JOIN `modules-users` 
ON `modules-users`.module_id=`modules-settings`.module_ticker WHERE role='N'
```

The SQL error is "*Could not execute the query*". **The strange thing is that query #2 works when I test it on PhpMyAdmin**.

What am I missing here? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you have `**` in the select clause. What you are trying to do here ?

Comment: what mysql client software are you using that generates the sql error?

Comment: I tried to put in bold. Took it off.

Comment: You have mentioned your table name as 'module-users' in the top and in query you have used as 'modules-user'. If that's a typo then please change accordingly.

Comment: Right. Just corrected it.

Comment: Your queries are fine, so the error is coming from something you've not described in your question. Can you give some more details of the environment on your server?

Comment: I have tried multiple times with vs. without the 2nd column (originally I thought it was because of an "ORDER BY"). I use SITEGROUND, the page is .php, the complete code is here: $sql="SELECT `modules-settings`.module_code FROM `modules-settings` JOIN `modules-users` ON `modules-users`.module_id=`modules-settings`.module_ticker WHERE role='N'";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die('Could not execute the query ' . mysqli_error()) ;

Comment: Does this query successfully run: `SELECT module_order FROM \`modules-users\` `

Comment: @Aidan: no it does not (!). You are into something here. Neither do : `SELECT 'modules-users'.module_order FROM 'modules-users'` nor `SELECT 'modules-users'.'module_order' FROM 'modules-users'`. BUT `SELECT role FROM 'modules-users'` works (!)

Comment: @SamanthaAlexandria is it possible PhpMyAdmin and your server are connecting to different (but very similar) versions of your database? E.g. a test version and a production version?

Comment: @Aidan: You found the source of the problem. The queries are good it's just that they point to a different but similarly named database. Hence my confusion. Very smart of you to find the solution! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this once where the mysql client on the server was a different version from the mysql server. Please check that your client and server are the same version. phpmyadmin bypasses the client and puts the query directly to the server, so phpmyadmin would work, even if the mysql client is a different version.

Comment: Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73. This does not provide a solution because I cannot change the version.

Comment: What do you mean by "phpmyadmin bypasses the client"? What is "the client" and what makes you think that PMA does something different than a regular website?

Comment: @NicoHaase phpmyadmin is a php application that makes use of PHPs own libraries for accessing the Mysql server. The OP is using libmysql. These are different code bases and they function independently.

Comment: I've never heard such, and I'm using PMA for more than ten years. PMA is not a "function", and the OP hasn't told us yet whether she uses PDO, mysql*, mysqli* or whatever else - most probably, PMA uses a similar connection method, and the same query should not behave differently if the library is exchanged

Comment: @NicoHaase read the OP's comment "Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73" 5 comments up. She's told us exactly what library is being used. PMA can be configured to use different libraries, but the default is mysqli

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure default database is the db that you are going to access.
2. try following query with after alter the tables names

`SELECT ms.module_code
FROM modules_settings ms 
JOIN modules_users mu ON mu.module_id=ms.module_ticker`

Comment: As mentioned, query #1 works both on PhpMyAdmin and on my server. I have no issue with that one.

Answer (score 0):

please try using this query :

```
SELECT ms.module_code, mu.module_order 
FROM modules-settings ms
JOIN modules-users mu
ON mu.module_id=ms.module_ticker WHERE role='N'
```

Comment: Can you highlight the differences and explain why they are neccessary?

Comment: I don't know - you should know that ;) But as others should be able to learn why the original query did not work, but yours does, you should add an explanation to your answer (not to the comment section)

Answer (score 0):

```
please try using this :  
  my database table  :
    I have created two tables:
    SELECT * FROM `modules-settings` ;

    module_ticker | name     | module_code  |
    +---------------+----------+--------------+
    |             1 | test     | testcode     |
    |             2 | demotest | demotestcode |


    SELECT * FROM `modules-users` LIMIT 0 , 30;
    +------+-----------+--------------+
    | role | module_id | module_order |
    +------+-----------+--------------+
    | N    |         1 |          123 |
    | 0    |         2 |          456 |
    +------+-----------+--------------+

    Now execute query :
    SELECT `modules-settings`.module_code, `modules-users`.module_order  FROM `modules-settings`  JOIN `modules-users`  ON `modules-users`.module_id=`modules-settings`.module_ticker WHERE role='N';
    +-------------+--------------+
    | module_code | module_order |
    +-------------+--------------+
    | testcode    |          123 |
    +-------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aidan pointed me to the solution. He knew the queries were fine so tried to find another reason by thinking out of the box. the pb was indeed that I was running these queries in 2 databases very similar but still different enough for my pb to occur.